# How to fix IE 6 bug elements aligns vertically?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, 960.gs

How to fix the page elememnt alignment in IE 6 ?

### [the site](http://www.automatydrzwiowe.pl/trunk/index.php?event=product&parent_id=37&menu_id=2)[image: IE6 bug]

Comment: Totally depends on your markup. Can't be told without seeing some HTML and CSS

Comment: @Pekka - his site: http://www.automatydrzwiowe.pl/trunk/index.php?event=product&parent_id=37&menu_id=2

Comment: You are probably suffering from the IE6 "float drop" problem. See [this article](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/expandingboxbug.html) for a decent explanation and some possible help.

Answer (score 0):

```
.tab_container {
    clear: right;
    float: left;
}
```

On the text div.

Comment: I don't know if your answer is correct, but I made a tiny change, see the revision history for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm not psychic, but I'll try.

you want the image to display where the red box is?

If so, give it the css `float: right;` and put it *before* the text, not after.

Answer (score 0):

`Float:left` both the text and Image containers with there own `width`.